# How to disable Home button without using the TYPE_KEYGUARD?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-notifications

i create a lockscreen application and i need to disable a home button, so if that phone is stolen, that phone can't be accessed.. my lockscreen is a fullscreen activity.. im use this code to disable a home button, but it gave me some bug. here's the code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow()
    {  
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
        super.onAttachedToWindow();  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
```

that code gave me some bug like a notification/status area still can be accessed even my activity on the full screen mode, if i turn off my display and turn on it again.. the bug is like this :

first time application started: (still no problem)

[image]

after i turn off my screen from power button and turn it on again:
[image]

the main problem is on the lockscreen.. when the notification area still can be accessed, then the lockscreen is not useful..

any idea how to solve this?? please help..

I am also facing the same problem when i press the end key button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my phone TYPE_KEYGUARD seems to override the fullscreen, no titlebar theme. The notification bar is always present. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);     
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```

Make your view stretch the entire screen and it will cover up the notification area. Your notification area may still be clickable (invisibly) but I believe if you catch all the key events on your view it should not propagate down to the bar.

Comment: Hello @e_x_p i am also facing the same problem. your solution is also not working after end button pressed. After end button pressed the notification area is visible again.

Comment: TYPE_KEYGUARD is deprecated in versions above SDK 14.  It won't work at all in target ADK version 21.

Comment: @KristyWelsh Exactly TYPE_KEYGUARD is deprecated in versions above SDK 14. Did you find any alternative solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SandeepMaram http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081968/illegalargumentexception-window-type-can-not-be-changed-after-the-window-is-add/34911898#34911898

Comment: @SandeepMaram http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300546/min-target-must-be-less-than-14-when-windowmanager-layoutparams-type-keyguard-us?lq=1

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.

Answer (score 4):

This is the working for the above issue..

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();
    }
```

Add `android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD` permission and give `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to Application

Comment: KeyguardLock is deprecated!! What's the alternative?

Answer (score 2):

In my Samusung Pocket, nothing above worked fine. I could make it finally after further search.

I put full screen them in your AndroidMainfest.xml like following (not in Acitivity code):

```
<activity
    android:name=".geo.activity.LockActivity"
    android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

And use keygurad onAttachedToWindow() method in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();
}
```

Exactly what I have wanted. Blocking HOME button and same after turning off/on.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, you should disable keyguard  in the onAttachedToWindow() method:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
@Override
 public void onAttachedToWindow() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onAttachedToWindow();  

     handler.postDelayed(mUpdateUiMsg, 100);

 }


 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
   return true;
  }
  if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
   return true;
  }

  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }


 private Runnable mUpdateUiMsg = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);


         }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

For a lockscreen Why don't you just use the following:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
}
```

If the user doesn't have a secure lock screen set, the app will just go to the home screen when your app closes. If the user does have a secure lockscreen set then the standard secure lockscreen will come up next no matter how your app closes. I guess I wouldn't worry about disabling the buttons. The user should be allowed to use the standard security features anyways, because they provide more security then you can guarantee from your app. Plus you don't have to spend the time coding secure unlock features.

Answer (score 0):

You can not control the behaviour of `Home Button`. It will do it's task and you need to adjust your app requirements.

For full screen add this in your activity tag in your manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: i can disable the home button with this: @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow()
    {  
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
        super.onAttachedToWindow();  
    } but it give me some bug like on the picture above.. any idea?

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i have add that code already for make a fullscreen activity, but the problem is when i turn off my screen and turn it on again, it will gave me some bug like the picture above.. :(

Comment: Hi Michael....Are you sure the above code u provided can disable the home button..coz i used the same code but the home button is not disabled....can u please help me?

Comment: You certainly can control the Home button. Maybe do a search of SO before posting such claims.