# How to disable Home button and keep your activity fullscreen?

Tags: android

I am developing a lock screen in my application and i have the same problem as given in the following link **[How to disable Home button without using the TYPE_KEYGUARD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7583553/1105865)**. I have used

```
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);     
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```

and added  **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"** in my mainfest.xml file. but still it is not working.

part of my mainfest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".LockActivity"  android:windowSoftInputMode ="stateAlwaysHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

    </activity>
```

**more details about my appliation is**

my applications works in background and as i get the command my lock activity is displayed. but the problem is when i turn off my screen from power button and the command comes after that when i unlock the screen then either status bar appears or i cannot block my home button.

Comment: `still it is not working` is a very precise problem description. Could you specify on which sdk version are you working? How is your manifest? What about more code, more details?

Comment: have you changed your theme ?

Comment: i have used onKeyDown to disable other keys and even tried with the <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"                  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>

Comment: yes have used Theme.NoTitlebar.Fullscreen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is working 2.2

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"  android:name=".Small"  
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Comment: my applications works in background and as i get the command my lock activity is displayed. but the problem is when i turn off my screen from power button and the command comes after that when i unlock the screen then either status bar appears or i cannot block my home button.

Comment: but i am not able to do it.please can you tell me more on yours application.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode why use this in place use android:label

Comment: my full screen works if their is no default screen guard on. but the problem is when the screen guard is on and the my activity sren has to appear.

Comment: i have tried in android 2.2 still not working and i have even removed android:windowSoftInputMode but still not working.

Comment: i want an screen lock application which works even when the screen is off, this screen lock must get invoked when command comes via sms,to lock the phone.

Comment: my application is first you  start app enter password and confine password in that....... and up some time anybody not touch that auto matically sereen is off. again we start appenter same password.this my app

Comment: ok but i want my application to get invoked externally only via sms.so if the sms comes and the screen is off then tats where my issue is.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void hideSystemUI() {

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE

                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```