# Notify when the user presses the home button

Tags: android

I know that I cant override the home button like with the back button. But can the android system fire an event if the home button is pressed? I want to catch this action in order to show a warning message if the user presses the home button. I've looked into several options, the most obvious one, for beginner would be to override the home button

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        // action goes here
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

But this doesnt work, and I'm completly aware of it.

The onPause method will be called once the current `Activity` finishes. This method will also be called when the user changes `Activity` in my application. So is there anyway I can show the user a notifying box, when he presses the home button?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869814/how-to-handle-home-button-in-android/13031697#13031697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is not possible to catch **home button pressed event like others**, it is a feature to protect the user.

But there is a **hack** for your situation:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);     
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```

[onAttachedToWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29)

> This is called when the **view is attached** to a window

You may read [Activity Lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for/8516056#8516056) how this hack works.

Also, [here is the evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7583553/323659) which shows this method works.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }
```

This can also help